# How do I use the colours on the The Fate Deck?

Tags: dragonlance-fifth-age

I am Narrating a game with the SAGA rules system and would like to know how others have used the card colours to assist in adjudicating actions with *The Fate Deck*.

Knowing this information could help me provide a better game experience to players.

> "Narrators who use only the action score based method are not taking
> full advantage of the many facets of the Fate Deck." *Fifth Age' Book
> One p.55*

The rules indicate these colours provide a "positive, negative and neutral identity" to each card, but provides little guidance beyond that.

Have you used the colours to help adjudicate an action? If so, how did it work? From your experience how would you recommend using the colours to help adjudicate an action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the colours for adjudicating outcomes with an even distribution. Ones that are not influenced by a characters ability scores.

SAGA rules refer to this aspect of the card as an *Aura color*.

A Narrator can use the *Aura color* of a card to determine the outcome of an action **instead** of using the number on the card.

Narrators more familiar with dice based games can think of the *Aura Color* as having the same probabilities as rolling a three sided die (D3).

Each suit has colored the numbers 1-3 White, 4-6 Red, 7-9 Black. Mechanically the cards are divided evenly such that the odds are uniform among the three outcomes.

\begin{array}
    \text{Aura/Moon}    &    \text{Values}  & \text{Symbolism} \\ \hline
    \text{White/Solinari}   & 1-3 & \text{Good/Positive} \\
    \text{Red/Lunitari} & 4-6   & \text{Neutral/Uncertain} \\
    \text{Black/Nuitari}    & 7-9 & \text{Evil/Negative} 
\end{array}

The rulebook provides one example for using the
*Aura Color*, that is to help determine an NPC's demeanour toward the Heroes; drawing 'White' could indicate kindness, 'Red' - mysterious, 'Black' - unfriendly.

Using the *Aura color* in this way means that the NPC has an equal chance of being kind, mysterious or unfriendly toward the Heroes.

Note; the suit of Dragons *Aura color* for all cards is Black. To achieve truly even probability distribution a Narrator should redraw if they pull a card from the suit of Dragons.

Alternatively, you may wish to include the suit of Dragons as a "mishap" (in game terms) where drawing a Dragon indicates a much worse outcome. Perhaps for the example above the NPC is actively hostile toward the heroes. Using the Fate Deck in this way skews toward negative outcomes, there is a 12% chance a drawn card is from the suit of Dragons.

Chart: *Fifth Age Book One* p. 54